# AND Gate in Logical Circuit

Tags: java

folks... I'll do my best to explain what the method does as it gets a lot of members from other classes but its logic should be straightforward.
So, in `AND Gate` of a logical circuit, if any input signal is `0` then the output is also `0`; if `all` of the input signals are `1` then the output is also `1`; but if we have signals `0` and `X(unknown signal)`, then the ouput is `0`; when `1` and `X` then the output should be `X`. 
I have a bug in the code of method because when, let's say `0X` signals are fed in the gate, I'm getting `X` instead of `0`. Could smb please help me? Note:`Signal.HI` is `1`, `Signal.LO` is `0`, `Signal.X` is `X`. Please let me know if any more information is needed.

```
public boolean propagate() 
    {
        Signal inputSignal;
        Signal outputFinalSignal;
        Signal temp = getOutput().getSignal();

        List<Wire> inputs = getInputs();

        for(int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++)
        {
            inputSignal = inputs.get(i).getSignal();
            if(inputSignal == Signal.LO)
            {
                getOutput().setSignal(Signal.LO);
                break;
            }

            else if(inputSignal == Signal.X)
            {
                getOutput().setSignal(Signal.X);
                break;
            }

            else 
            {
                getOutput().setSignal(inputSignal);
            }

        }
        ........................//Unnecessary for this problem code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your logic should be like this:

```
Signal result = Signal.HI; // default value is 1
for(int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++) {
    inputSignal = inputs.get(i).getSignal();
    if(inputSignal == Signal.LO) {
        // input is 0 - final result is 0 always, break immediately
        result = inputSignal;
        break;
    }
    else if(inputSignal == Signal.X) {
        // input is X, but we could have 0 later, so we store X and continue without break
        result = inputSignal;
    }
    else  {
        // signal is 1, just skip as we could meet 0 or X later or already met X
    }
}
getOutput().setSignal(result);
```

Comment: Cool! @Lashane Thank you! I got it from your snippet!

Answer (score -1):

Just continue the iteration after encountering X, and initialize to HI:

```
public boolean propagate() 
{
    Signal inputSignal;
    Signal outputFinalSignal = Signal.HI;
    Signal temp = getOutput().getSignal();

    List<Wire> inputs = getInputs();

    for(int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++)
    {
        inputSignal = inputs.get(i).getSignal();
        if(inputSignal == Signal.LO)
        {
            getOutput().setSignal(Signal.LO);
            break;
        }

        else if(inputSignal == Signal.X)
        {
            getOutput().setSignal(Signal.X);
        }

    }
```

Comment: what if all inputs are HI?

Comment: Then the result will be HI, because of the initialization.

Comment: if you looking at `outputFinalSignal ` and assume that it is used later, then this code will always return HI

Comment: You're correct, missed that. Bad naming. Your solution is complete.